# jquery function passsing variables

Tags: php, jquery

hi i am building a php mysql database pagination page, so i have a list of records 2 rows long at the bottom of the record i want a div which opens up when the span above it is clicked, how do i set up the jquery to make it so that it takes the id of the `<p>` and expands it in jquery

```
<span id="button1">Toggle</span>

<p id="p1">
hello<br/>hello
</p>

<script>
$("#button1").click(function () {
$("#p1").slideToggle("slow");
});
</script>
```

when i output it in php mysql the button will all have a different id and the p will have different ids as well

Comment: Since you're outputting "button1" into the `id` field in your PHP code, you can also output "button1" into the jQuery code in your PHP code. In other words, it doesn't matter that the names are dynamic, since you can set them in both places.

Comment: how about you give yout `p` a class name? this way you can select all at once

Answer (score 0):

```
//Jquery Code which calls toggle_visibility function
  $(".pOne").click(function(){
                toggle_visibility('partsIdThree'); 
            })
            .toggle( function() {
                $(this).children("span").text("[-]");
            }, function() {
                $(this).children("span").text("[+]");
            });

   //HTML Code
 <div id="parts_toogle_one">    
 <p class="pOne">Add Records <span>[+]</span></p>
       <div id="msg_body_one">
         <tr><td></td></tr>
       </div>
</div>       

  // Javascript code
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == "inline") {
        e.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if(e.style.display == "none") {
        e.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

Something like this..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic id retrieving, so you don't have to worry about the number of results..

For example:

```
<?php $i = 0;?>
<?php foreach($resultset as $result) : ;?>

<span class="activator" id="result<?php echo $i;?>">CLICK HERE</span>
<div id="panel_result<?php echo $i;?>">SLIDER DIV</div>

<!-- Do the rest of you processing of $result here; it just doesn't matter, for here you only need some identification, I used a number for convenience. -->  

<?php ++$i;?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Your jquery:

```
$('.activator').click(function(){
var the_id = $(this).attr('id');
var the_panel = $('#panel_' + the_id);
$(the_panel).slideToggle('slow');
});
```

So you don't have to write a jQuery command for each line you print in php, use just this snippet and it will work out by itself which panel to slide, according to which span is clicked.

Comment: this is so beautifully written